# Typescript: interface with generics - applying inside defined object

Tags: typescript, generics, types, interface, properties

I have an interface with generics:

```js
interface InterfaceWithGenerics<
  Dict extends Record<string, any>,
  Key extends keyof Dict = keyof Dict
> {
  key: Key;
  dictValueFormatter: ((key: Key, value: Dict[Key]) => any);
}
```

When I define object, which implements this interface, I expect generics to be applied to object properties and instantiate their types. For example:

```js
interface SomeDictionary {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  baz: boolean;
}

export const dictConfig: InterfaceWithGenerics<SomeDictionary>[] = [
  {
    key: 'foo',
    dictValueFormatter: (key, value) => `${key}:${value}`,
  }
];
```

But it not happens. VS Code shows the following typing for `dictValueFormatter` inside object with prop `key='foo'` **(Fact)**:

```js
(key: keyof SomeDictionary, value: string | number | boolean) => any
```

**Expected**:

```js
(key: 'foo', value: string) => any
```

**Question**: How to declare an interface with generics that will more specifically instantiate the types of properties in specific situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define discriminated union:

```js
type InterfaceWithGenerics<
  Dict extends Record<string, any>,
  > = {
    [Key in keyof Dict]: {
      key: Key;
      dictValueFormatter: ((key: Key, value: Dict[Key]) => any);
    }
  }

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]


interface SomeDictionary {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  baz: boolean;
}

export const dictConfig: Values<InterfaceWithGenerics<SomeDictionary>>[] = [
  {
    key: 'foo',
    dictValueFormatter: (key, value) => `${key}:${value}`,
  }
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdsCAnAZgQwMYQOoEtgAWA4hHMrhgM4A8AUFFACIXBQQAeicAJpVAEoQMAeyTdqlYElxwA5gBooaOCAB88%20lFVQAvFADemhgG0A0hBBQZUANYXhKJiwC6ALgNGGti%20-MgA3J4M3CwAamgANgCuEABiogC2aMCISO4AFOl2IL4WigBukTHuzBjAZhbOAJS62sogVYFeUAC%20mm20oJBQ4dEQNAAq2noDxtkOUAPOtDMyqehYUADKwgkQpcC4wnBoSJaGDCjCwu6S0nJNUABGu%205wUQlXyJc3AF7uV8cREMqBHRxgUSsERwSRQEJlADC2xQuFk7l6MRo8HmmBw%20GIpHIVGoKzWGy2Oz2qlUxmcuigxk0By82XcAHIjsJ6RpmhDgIi4olkqkMtkCkUIDUdNoAAYAEn02RarklhT6LVFrNatGc-iAA)

Please see my [article](https://catchts.com/safer-types#part_3)